# Rounded Image Drawable only drawing white

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas

I am following the rounded image tutorial from romain guy,

http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

I extracted the drawable to a class `RoundedDrawable` but when i try and use it to the bitmap, it will always paints white.

How do i fix this?

Comment: There are better ways to create rounded images, you should not use that method anymore. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26471808/599346

Comment: @tyczj that method doesn't work for me either. not even loading the bitmap =/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way
add this on your build.gradle`compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'`
and on your xml add

```
      <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/profile_image"
       android:layout_width="your size"
       android:layout_height="your size"
       android:src="@drawable/profile"
       app:civ_border_width="2dp"
       app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```